# ABout the bug: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/npy_data/signal_dataset/train/signals.npy'"

Tags: debugging

I am in process of making a ResNet (Residual Network) in order to classify signals. When i was trying to run my code then this bug happened and i dont know how to fix it. Any suggestions?
Thanks anyway!
I was trying to find out the problems here but it didnt exist